# Sync desktop and laptop environments

Tags: operating-system

I have a laptop and I have a desktop. Is it possible to have these two machines share the same environment, so that if I installed something on one I also have it on the other. They share the same folders, same files, same applications, same states.

Is there software that makes this possible with any operating system?

Comment: For what OSs are you looking for? At least for Windows, Windows 10 bundles some of this already, at least for some settings. But sharing state between different OS will be challenging, if at all possible. As for software, there is no way around reinstalling it everywhere you go.

Comment: I was thinking something more like using Docker container, so that I can push my state and then downloading on another machine.